# Docu Sign Text Tab Fields auto copying when typing issue

Tags: docusignapi

I'm adding two different text tabs yet when I enter text in one tab then the content auto copies to the other field and vice versa, any reason wy this is happening?

JB

Comment: Both tabs most likely have the same LABEL value, therefore they represent the same content and DocuSign is enforcing that for you. Make the tab labels unique to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the JSON you're sending it's most likely as Luis has mentioned- you are most likely sending the same `tabLabel` for your fields.  Try using unique tab labels for your text tabs and they should be independent.